# Getting Date with Start time of the Day

Tags: android, date, kotlin, datetime, calendar

I am using below function to take the today's date :

```
fun getCurrentDateTime(dateFormat: String): String {
    val Datetime: String
    val c = Calendar.getInstance()
    val dateformat = SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat, Locale.getDefault())
    Datetime = dateformat.format(c.time)
    return Datetime
}
```

I have filter for **today** to sort fetch today's filtered data. But, With the above function I am filtering with the same values,
Means **start date** for Today and **end date** for Today are both same.

I want it different.
Means :
Start Date should be **1639560609 (Wednesday, 15 December 2021 00:00:00 GMT+05:30)**
and
End Date should be **Current time** (which I am getting with above function)

So, The Issue you got that I want the Today's start Date with start time of the day.

How ? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a desired `String` format? I mean the pattern, it is not included in your question. Why do you use this outdated api (`java.util.Calendar` & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`) and not the modern one: `java.time`?

Comment: Never use `Calendar`, `Date`, and `SimpleDateFormat`. Those classes are now legacy, supplanted entirely by the modern *java.time* classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `LocalDateTime` to get current date and start of the day

```
val dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE, d MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss")
val localDate = LocalDate.now()   // your current date time 
val startOfDay: LocalDateTime = localDate.atStartOfDay() // date time at start of the date
val timestamp = startOfDay.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant().toEpochMilli() // start time to timestamp
Log.d("Date:", "start date $timestamp")
Log.d("Date:", "start date parsed ${startOfDay.format(dateFormatter)}")
```

**Output:**
Start Date Timestamp : 1639506600000
Parsed TimeStamp: Wednesday, 15 December 2021 00:00:00

**Edit** : To get end of date time

```
val endOfDate: LocalDateTime = localDate.atTime(LocalTime.MAX)
val timestampEnd = endOfDate.atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")).toInstant().epochSecond
```

Comment: How can I get 1639506600 instead of 1639506600000 ?

Comment: Use `epochSecond` instead of `.toEpochMilli()`

Comment: I am asking for endTime of the Today.

Comment: Yes it will return today's end time , as local date is current date `LocalDate.now() `

Comment: okay there I need to change the zon id to utc. correct ?

Comment: If you want timestamp in UTC , other view it will be system default timezone

Comment: Never use `LocalDateTime` class when trying to track specific moments. That class lacks the context of a time zone or offset from UTC. So that class cannot represent a specific point on the time line.

Answer (score 2):

Capture the current moment.

```
Instant now = Instant.now() ;
```

Understand that, for any given moment, **the date varies** around the globe by time zone. At one moment, it can be “tomorrow” in Tokyo Japan  while simultaneously “yesterday” in Edmonton Alberta Canada .

## Specific time zone

Get the date in effect at that moment in a specific time zone. Here we use the time zone of India .

```
ZoneId zKolkata = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ;
LocalDate todayKolkata = now.atZone( zKolkata ).toLocalDate() ;
```

Get the first moment of the date in that zone.

```
ZonedDateTime startOfTodayKolkata = todayKolkata.atStartOfDay( zKolkata ) ;
```

Get the count of whole seconds from first moment of 1970 UTC to that first moment of that date in Kolkata.

```
long secondsSinceEpochToStartOfTodayKolkata = startOfTodayKolkata.toInstant().getEpochSecond() ;
```

If you want to track the full length of the day, use Half-Open approach. In Half-Open, the beginning is inclusive while the ending is exclusive. So a full day starts at the first moment of one date and runs up to, but does not include, the beginning of the *following* day.

```
ZonedDateTime startOfTomorrowKolkata = todayKolkata.plusDays( 1 ).atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

Track the full day as a pair of `Instant` objects, using the  `Interval` class from the *ThreeTen-Extra* library.

```
Interval allDayTodayKolkata = Interval.between( startOfTodayKolkata , startOfTomorrowKolkata ) ;
```

## UTC (offset of zero)

In contrast, determine the first moment of today’s date as experienced with an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds.

```
LocalDate todayUtc = now.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ).toLocalDate() ;
ZonedDateTime startOfDayUtc = todayUtc.atStartOfDay( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
long secondsSinceEpochToStartOfDayUtc = startOfDayUtc.toInstant().getEpochSecond() ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how can you can get the number of hours later time from current time in Kotlin:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73050414/7126848