# How to get today's timestamp in GMT format - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, datetime, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I am using below function to fetch the today's start Timestamp in kotlin- Android.

```
fun getTimeStampForStartOfTheDay(): String {
    val localDate = LocalDate.now()   // your current date time
    val startOfDay: LocalDateTime = localDate.atStartOfDay() // date time at start of the date
    val timestamp = startOfDay.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant()
        .epochSecond // start time to timestamp
    return timestamp.toString()
}
```

The TimeStamp am getting is as : **1639593000**

> GMT: Wednesday, 15 December 2021 18:30:00
>
> Your time zone: Thursday, 16 December 2021 00:00:00 GMT+05:30
>
> Relative: 11 hours ago

But timestamp should be **1639612800**

> GMT: Thursday, 16 December 2021 00:00:00
>
> Your time zone: Thursday, 16 December 2021 05:30:00 GMT+05:30
>
> Relative: 5 hours ago

How can I achieve this ? Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to capture the first moment of the day in a specific time zone such as India or first moment of the day at the prime meridian (an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `ZoneId.systemDefault()` to UTC TimeZone

```
 val timestamp = startOfDay.atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")).toInstant().epochSecond
```

Comment: Thanks @Nitish. By using atStartOfDay() am getting the start time of the today. But do you have any idea that : How can I get the endTime of the today ?

Comment: Yes sure , I have edited my answer here - [start of date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70361623/getting-date-with-start-time-of-the-day/70362011#70362011) , as it feels more suitable there instead of here, as your other question is much more relatable to this query

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.now( z ).atStartOfDay( z ).toInstant().getEpochSecond() ;
```

## Details

I am not sure what is going wrong in your code, but it seems to be a matter of time zone.

Another problem is that you rely implicitly on the JVM’s current default time zone. Any code in any thread of any app can change that default at any moment. So, better to specify your desired or expected time zone. Or at least capture the default once and reuse, rather than accessing the current default multiple times.

And your code is overwrought, jumping through unnecessary hoops.

In Java syntax:

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Or specify: ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ;
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
ZonedDateTime startOfToday = today.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
Instant instant = startOfToday.toInstant() ;
long countOfSecondsSinceEpochReference = instant.getEpochSecond() ;
```

See also [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70374599/642706) to a similar Question.

Comment: Thanks @Basil sir. By using atStartOfDay() am getting the start time of the today. But do you have any idea that : How can I get the endTime of the today ?

Comment: @JaiminModi The last moment of a day is infinitely divisible, and therefore awkward. Better to define a span of time using Half-Open approach where the beginning is inclusive while the ending is exclusive. This allows for neatly abutting spans without a gap. So a day starts at first moment of that date and runs up to, but does not include the first moment of the *following* date. Search Stack Overflow to learn more. This has been covered many times.

Comment: @BasilBourque `epochSecond  is a method, not a field.` - above code is written in kotlin and not java. In kotlin getter/setter are automatically defined so we can access it using field name(internally it's getter method only)

Comment: @Nitish Thanks for that, I’ll correct the Answer.